# How to determine placeholder dependency in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a few symbolic variables to fetch, I need to know which placeholders are dependency.

In Theano, we have:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T

x, y, z = T.scalars('xyz')
u, v = x*y, y*z
w = u + v

th.gof.graph.inputs([w])  # gives [x, y, z]
th.gof.graph.inputs([u])  # gives [x, y]
th.gof.graph.inputs([v])  # gives [y, z]
th.gof.graph.inputs([u, v])  # gives [x, y, z]
```

How to do the same thing in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3):

There's not an built-in function (that I know of), but it's easy to make one:

```py
# Setup a graph
import tensorflow as tf
placeholder0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])
placeholder1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])
constant0 = tf.constant(2.0)
sum0 = tf.add(placeholder0, constant0)
sum1 = tf.add(placeholder1, sum0)

# Function to get *all* dependencies of a tensor.
def get_dependencies(tensor):
    dependencies = set()
    dependencies.update(tensor.op.inputs)
    for sub_op in tensor.op.inputs:
        dependencies.update(get_dependencies(sub_op))
    return dependencies

print(get_dependencies(sum0))
print(get_dependencies(sum1))
# Filter on type to get placeholders.
print([tensor for tensor in get_dependencies(sum0) if tensor.op.type == 'Placeholder'])
print([tensor for tensor in get_dependencies(sum1) if tensor.op.type == 'Placeholder'])
```

Of course, you could throw the placeholder filtering into the function as well.

Comment: This recursion is probably inefficient on "Fibonacci" like graphs, but indeed a good start point.

Comment: if there is only one dependency on placeholder, say y1 = x, where x is a placeholder, then this get_depednececy function cannot find it.